# Ruby on Rails get interval values between start_at and end_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, time, each

I have question about processing time in increments in my Rails app.

I have a Schedule model with these columns:

```
:user_id => 1,
:day => “Sunday”,
:start_at => “08:00AM”,
:end_at => “03:30PM”,
:average_time => “30” # this average time in minutes
```

I need to loop from the `start_at` to the `end_at` in 30-minute increments, like so:

```
08:00 AM

08:30 AM

09:00 AM

09:30 AM

10:00 AM

…

…

03:30 PM
```

How can I process the difference between times incrementally like this?

Comment: how do you know what day it is?  is the range guaranteed to a single day?  Do you just need to print to the screen?

Comment: I have records for each day, and this example for Sunday

Comment: Do the times always start and end with a whole or half hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `step` for a range loop to do that.  Here's an example for your model:

```
total_minutes = (schedule.end_at - schedule.start_at) / 60

(0..total_minutes).step(30) do |minutes|
  time = schedule.start_at + minutes*60
  puts "#{time.strftime('%H:%M')}"
end
```

This starts by calculating `total_minutes` from the difference between the `start_at` and `end_at` times, converting seconds to minutes.  This assumes that these are Ruby Time objects and not Strings; strings would need to be converted to Time before using this code.

Next, the loop progresses from the `start_at` in increments of 30 minutes by adding the minutes for each loop iteration (* 60) to `start_at`.  At each interval, the loop prints the time, until it reaches or exceeds `end_at`.

Comment: @zippax Glad to hear that!  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Convert everything to seconds, parse the times and multiply your "average" by 60. Then simply do your loop from start_time to end_time incrementing by average. Convert back to time and print or do whatever you want.

In general, you need to convert everything to equals to be able to work on it. If that's seconds or minutes, all should work. Seconds makes it easy to work with time objects.